# Trying to find a marginal distribution from a joint PMF

Tags: probability-distributions, summation

I'm struggling with a question that asks to "find the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X = x$" which I know requires finding the marginal distribution of $X$. However, I'm having trouble doing that:

The Joint PMF is: $$\frac{1}{e^2y!(x-y)!}$$, so the marginal for X is

$$\sum_{y=0}^{n}\frac{1}{e^2y!(x-y)!}$$ but I have no idea how to simplify that...

Thanks!

Comment: What is the support for the pmf?

Comment: Stirling's approximation for $n!$, may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not look right, is the support actually $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb N^2:0\leq y\leq x\}$?

Then $p_X(x) ~{= \sum_{y=0}^x \frac{1}{e^2 y!(x-y)!} \mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)\cap\Bbb N} \\ =\frac{1}{e^2 x!}\sum_{y=0}^x \frac{x!}{y!(x-y)!}\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)\cap\Bbb N}  \\ = \frac{2^x}{e^2 x!}\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;\infty)\cap\Bbb N} }$

Comment: By support, if you mean conditions, y<=x definitely makes sense/is necessary but it's not specifically specified in the question?

Comment: The support for a probability mass function are the interval over which where its value is not zero.